# Rotating a straight line 360 degrees

Tags: geometry

I am creating a 3D object based on a sketch.

I just wanted to know if I were to rotate the line which shows 14.24 (I got this value by diving 28.50 by 2) by 360 degrees ,

Then what would be the diameter of the circle ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diameter would just be $28.5$.

When you have solids of revolution, the **height** of the figure becomes the **radius** of the cross section.

Comment: Okay I understand, I have made a mistake in my drawing then. Thank you.